# Google maps circle overlay . how to call a function on after drag complete?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Guys after a long R&D I was able to draw a circle and put markers which are inside that area of circle based on position and radius.

I'm calling a function which triggers whenever the radius or the position of the circle changes..
 It is working fine( function triggers and it fetches the markers from the database.) but the function is called when the circle is being dragged(some 100 times). i want that function to called OnDragComplete..  i didn't find any such events Google API..
below is my code.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'distance_changed', function() {
 displayInfo(distanceWidget);
  searchLocations();
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'position_changed', function() {
 displayInfo(distanceWidget);
 searchLocations();
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a "dragging" property to the widget on the mouse events and check it in your other functions:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'mousedown', function() {
    distanceWidget.dragging = true;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'mouseup', function() {
    distanceWidget.dragging = false;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'position_changed', function() {
    if (distanceWidget.dragging === false) {
        displayInfo(distanceWidget);
        searchLocations();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea michael!! Your idea  should work !but for some reason mousedown or mouseup events are not  triggering..

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue. we can use drag and dragend event listener inside 
DistanceWidget function and use marker instance to listen

```js
function DistanceWidget(map) {
  this.set('map', map);
  this.set('position', map.getCenter());

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    lat: $('input[name=lat]').val(),
    lng: $('input[name=lng]').val(),
    draggable: true,
    crossOnDrag: false,
    cursor: 'crosshair',
    title: 'Drag to change circle radius!',
    icon: 'assets/front/images/pin.png',
  });

  
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function(e) {
    console.log('starting');
  });
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
    // Trigger once u drop the widget marker
    
    console.log('end');
  });

}
```