# google map addListener method loops for n nmb of times

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

in the below code  GetPropBasedOnRadius(); method loops for n nmb of times 
i need to call that method only when the dragging event is completed
im not sure how to do this

any help will be appreciated

```
google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'distance_changed', function () {

    displayInfo(distanceWidget);
});


google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'position_changed', function () {

    displayInfo(distanceWidget);
    GetPropBasedOnRadius();
});
```

Comment: what type of object is `distanceWidget`?  The Google API doesn't have any documented class that has a `distance_changed` event, and it's got several with a `position_changed` event.

Comment: /**
  * Update the radius when the distance has changed.
  */
 RadiusWidget.prototype.distance_changed = function() {
  this.set('radius', this.get('distance') * 1000);
 };  its used for default radius of 1km

im not having any prob with distance_changed event 
in position_changed event if i call any mehod its looping n nmb of time

Comment: and mouse events are not working( eg. mousemove, mouseup)
please help me out in this

Comment: so `distanceWidget` is an instance of your `RadiusWidget` class?  What does the rest of that class look like; is it extending some existing Google class?  That might give us some clue if there's a different event you could use instead of `position_changed`

Comment: rest of that class means ??? u cud refer to below link im facing same problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637967/google-maps-circle-overlay-how-to-call-a-function-on-after-drag-complete

Comment: Well that question has an answer... so there's your answer

Comment: but its not working mouse events are not working :-(

Comment: mousedown or mouseup events are not triggering..

Comment: can you please help me on this im struggling

Comment: You need to add more of your code to your question

Comment: Sorry im trying to add my complete code but there is some issue 
if u could share your mail id i can send my code to u

Comment: Try putting it on somewhere like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yes  duncan hear is the link http://jsfiddle.net/MpunT/1/
i have added my code please let me know if u need any thing more 
Thanks for ua help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is working, I think you should just need to change your event listener from `position_changed` (which will fire constantly as your DistanceWidget is dragged) to `dragend` (which will only fire after they stop dragging).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'dragend', function () {
    displayInfo(distanceWidget);
    GetPropBasedOnRadius();
});
```

Comment: yes i tried this but if i put  dragend  to listener this event will not fire at all :-(
hope there will be some more solution with u 
thanks for your help